# Twitch tmi.js /host no_permissions

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, twitch

I am trying to write a simple script using `tmi.js`.

But every time I attempt to run the command:-

I have omitted the channel out for this post.

```
client.say(`#${channel}`, `/host twitch`);
```

or

```
client.host(`#${channel}`, `twitch`).then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
}).catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err.toLocaleString());
});
```

I get the following error:-

```
 info: [#<xxxxxxxx>] You don't have permission to perform that action.
```

I have uploaded the full code to [jsFIddle](https://jsfiddle.net/56ucx82q/1/)

Any help towards this would be greatly appreciated.

ps.

Just a note, I can run other commands, without any issues eg:-

```
client.say(`#${channel}`, 'Hey Peeps');
```

I have also tried to use

```
client.host(`#${channel}`, `#${channelToHost}`)
```

But I still get the same issue, I am the broadcaster of this channel and have logged in to the IRC using my username and oAuth token.

Here is the full output of the log on debug mode:-

```
[11:25] info: Connecting to irc-ws.chat.twitch.tv on port 80..
[11:25] info: Sending authentication to server..
[11:25] info: Connected to server.
[11:25] info: [#xxxxxxxxxx] Executing command: /host streamerhouse
[11:25] info: [#xxxxxxxxxx] You don't have permission to perform that action.
(node:28434) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: no_permission
```

Comment: When sending a message I notice that the debug is returning a `'user-type': null` even though I have tried it as the broadcaster account and a separate account using editor privileges, if I add the account as mod I get the mod usertype but still the same error for the no_permission

Answer (score 0):

try updated your oauth here: https://twitchapps.com/tmi/

Only the broadcaster and editors of that channel can use the host comman. Make sure the bot is either using your account in the channel, or if it is a different account then make sure you give it the editor role from your Roles menu in the dashboard.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I am the broadcaster of the channel. I have connected to the irc using my username and my oAuth key but it will not allow me to run the host command.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your bot to use permission based commands like for example: `/raid`, your bot needs to be an editor on your Twitch channel in order for it to run it. If you don't have this setup you will get the current error.

[image: Bot Editor role]